# Use a random number to render that corresponding object ID's data in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, random, render

I'm trying to create an react app where you press a button and it gives you a date night option and a corresponding image.
I created a small array of objects within dates.js ex:

```
export const dates = [
    {
        id: 0,
        name: "Comedy Club",
        image: "/assets/images/comic.jpg",   
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name:"Piano Bar ",
        image: "/assets/images/piano-bar.jpg",
    },
```

Then I created a GetDates.js to use the random method & corresponding onclick event. Below is where I'm stuck. I've changed this code 100 times based on various previous answers and youtube tutorials but I receive errors or they are not exactly what I'm trying to render. Can you please let me know from this last update what is needed to display the dates.name & dates.image based on the randomId method used below? Again, I've altered this so much from my original attempt that I'm not sure this is the best approach. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
class GetDates extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      image: "",
    };
  }

  randomSelect() {
    const randomId = dates[Math.floor(Math.random() * dates.length)].id;
    this.setState({ ...this.props.dates[randomId] });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="results-container">
        <button className="date-btn" onclick={this.randomSelect}>
          GET DATE IDEAS!
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default GetDates;
```

Comment: Can you post what error you are getting, or what it is incorrectly rendering?

Comment: Hello. In this instance the button/onclick is not functioning. I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prop is called `onClick` in React, not `onclick` (like the HTML attribute).
You should also render the currently selected item, which you currently do not. In general you should also use functional components instead of class components. Also be careful with `this` as it may not refer to what you think it does. When you use an array function `() => setCurDate()` you can be sure that `this` is bound correctly. I recommend you read the [MDN docs for 'this'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) in order to understand why that is and what you can do to prevent it.

Here a simple implementation tackling all the abovementioned issues.

```js
const dates = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: "Comedy Club",
    image: "https://dummyimage.com/600x100/000/fff&text=Comedy+Club",
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Piano Bar ",
    image: "https://dummyimage.com/600x100/000/fff&text=Piano+Bar",
  },
];

function GetDates() {
  // state for the currently selected item
  const [curDate, setCurDate] = React.useState(randomSelect());

  function randomSelect() {
    // select one item at random (it is possible that the same image is selected more than once in a row)
    const selected = Math.floor(Math.random() * dates.length);
    return dates[selected];
  }

  return (
    <div className="results-container">
      {/* onClick update the state by creating a copy of the object to trigger a state update */}
      <button className="date-btn" onClick={() => setCurDate({...randomSelect()})}>
        GET DATE IDEAS!
      </button>
      {/* Render the currently selected item */}
      <h3>{curDate.name}</h3>
      <img src={curDate.image} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<GetDates />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This is very close.  Do you know what would be causing the images to render as a broken thumbnail? (The only eidt I did was remove react from in front of use state and instead imported useState from react since it was stating that react wasn't defined when using your provided code. The functionality is now working but the image is not rendering correctly.

Comment: Yes, usually you would use `import ...` but that does not work on StackOverflow. You need to make sure the images exist at those paths. So make sure `/assets/images/comic.jpg` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting an error upon clicking the button, then it might be due to the `randomSelect` method not being bound to the class.

Try adding the bind call in your constructor, so you would have:

```
constructor(props) {
    ...

    this.randomSelect = this.randomSelect.bind(this);
}
```

You can read more on this here: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html